# Play two webcam feeds on top of each other in fullscreen mode

Tags: video, camera

I'm looking for a linux app which I can configure to play on launch the feed of two connected webcams. The feed of webcam 1 should be fullscreen, while the second one should play in a specified rectangle on top of the fullscreen one.

Which linux application allows me to do this? I already tried cheese, motion and vlc without success

Comment: How about starting two instances? One in fullscreen and a second one with smaller size and position? `mpv` for example can be started in fullscreen mode or have position an size predefined from the command line. Just mash you two instances in a single script to start and you're fine.

Comment: that would give me a window around the second window - I want it overlayed over the first video feed without any border (or maximally 1 pixel wide)

Comment: As in the `--no-border` option?